# Google places API nearby search for localities producing weird results

Tags: google-maps

I've been playing with the places API recently more specifically for nearby suburbs from a given lat/long coord.

I specified that I want to show types of 'locality' from a given coord which was point cook in Victoria, and also gave a radius of 5000 or 5km. The results were fine, however when I increased the radius to 10000' the results reduced in size, and when I gave a radius of 30000' the only locality that showed up was melbourne. Weird.

Now I know that without specifying rankby distance it shows results based on popularity, so I changed it to rankby distance, showing types of 'locality', but that produced an error of zero results!

I don't understand why this is the case and I tried different types such as sub locality, postal code and geocode, all producing zero results. However, if i specified types such as food, the results started to show up.

All I want to be able to do is get a list of postcodes and or suburbs near a given coord or within a radius. I'm beginning to believe with the API is buggy or one cannot do this with the places API?

Many thanks in advance and I hope someone can clarify this.

I'm also considering using a set of localised nearby postcodes as opposed to relying on google however the client was initially adamant they wanted to have a similar feature to that on airbnb.com which I believe uses google places only.

Comment: Same issue here. Ever resolve it?